# Strategy for the Krenko revenge campaign

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

I am currently trying to beat Krenko in the revenge campaign in Magic 2013 for the iPad and it is turning out to be quite problematic...

Does anyone have any tips on how to beat him?  I have all the decks unlocked plus expansion decks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krenko's deck is all about the speed, but his creatures are fairly weak, so there are a few different avenues of attack that work against him.

Strategy 1 - Use the other swarm deck. The Peacekeepers deck is almost as fast as the goblin deck and has larger creatures in it. You are looking to gambit off your creatures to prevent Krenko from reaching critical mass, before sealing it with your larger creatures and those with flying. You also want make sure that you kill off/exile the direct damage goblins as soon as they show up.

Strategy 2 - Put the brakes on. This one is for the red and black decks. It's also the best way to take the goblin deck down in multiplayer, as well. You slow the deck down till you can get enough mana to cast a few game enders. Basically, you are going to trade some of your life point total, while you kill the biggest threats so that the deck is out of cards in hand when you get to that magical 6/7 mana range. You can afford to lose about 8 life without putting yourself in one turn killed territory. You also want to save your board clear spells until you can take out 3 or 4 goblins, directing your single killers at the big threats of the goblin chieftains and the mob boss.

The biggest thing that you need to do is keep the pressure on at all times. The goblin deck is super aggressive, but it has little to no defense. If you can outlast the savagery or put it on the defensive, you are almost guaranteed a win. You also want to kill a goblin off whenever you can because once that deck hits five goblins out, you are looking at a terrible time after that.

Comment: I used the Liliana Vess's Obedient Dead deck.  I was able to apply pressure by using Blister Beetle ability, Murder, Crippling Blight, Public Execution and Incremental Blight.